# Date format error

Tags: sql, date, oracle10g

```
declare
   v_date date;

   CURSOR abc 
   is
      select a_date
        from abc
       where part_id ='E00000001';
begin
   open abc; 
   fetch abc into v_date;
   close abc;

   dbms_output.put_line('date is '||v_date);
end;
/
```

> Here my date that is been fetched is '31/12/2099 23:59:59',Now the issue is that when i fetch this into v_date using cursor its coming ....date is 31/DEC/99
>
> > What may be the issue

I am using oracle as RDBMS

Comment: what column type is `a_date` exactly ?

Comment: ok - please see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one thing that bothers me with your code - `abc` is the name of the table and of the cursor... that's bad practice IMHO.

As for the date format problem try

```
dbms_output.put_line('date is '||TO_CHAR ( v_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') );
```

The output you see is most probably the result of some db/session-level NLS setting regarding the date format which is used when converting a `DATE` to a `VARCHAR2` . My code uses an explicit date format to work independently of that setting (which is NOT ideal since it might make it problematic in situations where localization/globalization is needed!).

Comment: Yahia : for abc name ,i have just prepare a poc code to display,its not the actual code.In actual code i am fetching the date into a record from cursor .So In select we need to do some operation for fetching